# Como tratar uma String em formato de JSON?

Tags: java, json, string

Digamos que eu receba o seguinte conteúdo que fique armazenado em uma String:

```
{
    "client_id": 1580,
    "videos": 4,
    "remote_urls": [{
            "url": "rtsp://aniceurl.com"
        },
        {
            "url": "rtsp://aniceurl.com"
        },
        {
            "url": "rtsp://aniceurl.com"
        },
        {
            "url": "rtsp://aniceurl.com"
        }
    ],
    "action": "start"
}
```

Reconheço o JSON e tudo mais, mas ele está salvo numa String, não num JSONObject. Gostaria de saber como eu posso extrair as informações dele e armazenar em variáveis/arrays, para eu poder trabalhar com esses dados.

[]'s!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode usar o [Gson](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/) da google, é super simples, é só criar uma classe que tenha exatamente os mesmos atributos do json e fazer o parser, olha o exemplo que fiz com seu json, apenas utilizando o método `fromJson(meuJson, MinhaClasse.class)`:

**ClienteDTO**

```
import java.util.List;

public class ClienteDTO {
    private Integer client_id;
    private Integer videos;
    private List<RemoteUrlDTO> remote_urls;
    private String action;

    public Integer getClient_id() {
        return client_id;
    }
    public void setCliente_id(Integer cliente_id) {
        this.client_id = cliente_id;
    }
    public Integer getVideos() {
        return videos;
    }
    public void setVideos(Integer videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
    }
    public List<RemoteUrlDTO> getRemote_urls() {
        return remote_urls;
    }
    public void setRemote_urls(List<RemoteUrlDTO> remote_urls) {
        this.remote_urls = remote_urls;
    }
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClienteDTO [cliente_id=" + client_id + ", videos=" + videos + ", remote_urls=" + remote_urls
                + ", action=" + action + "]";
    }
}
```

**RemoteUrlDTO**

```
public class RemoteUrlDTO {
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RemoteUrlDTO [url=" + url + "]";
    }
}
```

**Classe para testar e demonstrar o GSON:**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String json = "{\n" +
                "    \"client_id\": 1580,\n" +
                "    \"videos\": 4,\n" +
                "    \"remote_urls\": [{\n" +
                "            \"url\": \"rtsp://aniceurl.com\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"url\": \"rtsp://aniceurl.com\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"url\": \"rtsp://aniceurl.com\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"url\": \"rtsp://aniceurl.com\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ],\n" +
                "    \"action\": \"start\"\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "\n";


        ClienteDTO clienteDTO = g.fromJson(json, ClienteDTO.class);

        System.out.println(clienteDTO);
    }
}
```

**Resultado após execução do teste**

```
ClienteDTO [cliente_id=1580, videos=4, remote_urls=[RemoteUrlDTO [url=rtsp://aniceurl.com], RemoteUrlDTO [url=rtsp://aniceurl.com], RemoteUrlDTO [url=rtsp://aniceurl.com], RemoteUrlDTO [url=rtsp://aniceurl.com]], action=start]
```

Comment: Acho que estou entendendo como usar! Você poderia me explicar só a parte do "fromJson(meuJson, MinhaClasse.class)"? Como ela funciona? Que classe eu devo colocar como parametro? Obrigado!

Comment: Simples, no método fromJson ele espera dois parametros, o primeiro é uma string que contem o seu json e o outro é a classe que tem os mesmos atributos do seu json, com isso ele consegue fazer o parse e te devolve um objeto, aí vc consegue manipular conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: vc não precisa mexer nesse remoteurldto, pois se mexer vai quebrar o parser do json para objeto, o que pode fazer é acessar o objeto da url dessa forma : for (int i = 0; i < numVideo; i++) { mediaPlayer[i].playMedia(clienteDTO.getRemote_urls().get(i).getUrl()); }

Comment: estou partindo do pressuposto de que vc recebeu um json e fez o parser para a classe cliente, logo vc deve usar essa mesma instância para fazer esse procedimento.